# Change in state and scope in python

Tags: python, flask

I am working with the requests python library and flask.

I'd like to open a page "example.com" and then follow a link to open "example.com/linked_page.html"

My plan is to use request sessions like this (simplified):

```
def main():
    s = requests.Session()  
    d = {'session':s, 'e': None}

    html = get_base_page(d)


def get_base_page(dict):
    s = dict['session']
    html = s.get("example.com")
    return html
```

Since the state of the session is changed within a function will that affect the value of "s" within the 'main' (global?) scope. Also is there a good discussion of this anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_base_page` function has its own namespace, so there would be no interference between the two `s` variables.

You can access global variables from the `get_base_page` function.
But if you want to assign a value to them you need to declare them as `global`.
Otherwise they would be created in the function's local namespace, as it does occur in your case.

See [this](http://spartanideas.msu.edu/2014/05/12/a-beginners-guide-to-pythons-namespaces-scope-resolution-and-the-legb-rule/) article for a good tutorial about namespaces and scope (LEGB rule)

Reading your question again, I think the point we need to clarify is how the `s` object is stored as the value of the key named `session` in the `d` dictionary.

Now fire up python and do the following (>>> is the python prompt):

```
>>> s = 42
>>> d = {'session': s, 'key2': 8}
>>> d
{'key2': 8, 'session': 42}
>>> s = 3
>>> d
{'key2': 8, 'session': 42}
```

When you say `s = 3`, you are telling python to make the `s` name point to/indicate the value `3`. You are not overwriting the value itself.

Now let's do the same thing with a generic object of a class we define:

```
>>> class A(object):
...  def __init__(self, n):
...   self.n = n
... 
>>> s = A(42)
>>> d = {'session': s, 'key2': 8}
>>> d['session'].n
42
>>> s.n = 30
>>> d['session'].n
30
```

See the difference? The `s` name and the `session` key point to/indicate the same object instance. So when you change its attributes (reaching them through either name), the change will affect both.

Please refer to [this](http://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/) article for immutable/mutable objects.

Practice with all python types and see what happens. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The two `s` variables are independent of each other.... unless you use `global s`.